# An extension hides a property that I want to access. Workarounds?

Tags: ios, swift, swift-extensions

I am using two pods: [`DropDown`](https://github.com/AssistoLab/DropDown) and [`SwiftyUtils`](https://github.com/tbaranes/SwiftyUtils).

`DropDown` adds in a `UIView` subclass called `DropDown`. The `DropDown` class defines its own `width` property. Instead of setting the `frame`, the client code has to set the width of the drop down menu using this property. It is defined like this:

```
public var width: CGFloat? {
    didSet { setNeedsUpdateConstraints() }
}
```

`SwiftyUtils` on the other hand, added an extension to all `UIView`s. In the extension, there is a `width` property as well. *This* `width` property is simply returning `frame.width` so that people can write less code. It is defined like this:

```
public var width: CGFloat {
    get { return frame.width }
    set { frame = frame.with(width: newValue) } // frame.with() is defined in SwiftyUtils as well
}
```

The problem comes when I try to set the `DropDown`'s menu width using the `width` property defined in `DropDwon`. The compiler thinks that I mean the `width` property defined in the extension in the `SwiftyUtils` module.

How can I tell the compiler that what I mean is the `width` in `DropDown`, not the `width` in `SwiftyUtils`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed this problem by a little trick.

The `width` in `DropDown` is of type `CGFloat?`, but the `width` in `SwiftyUtils` is of type `CGFloat`. This means that if I pass an optional `CGFloat`, the compiler will understand that I meant the `width` in `DropDown`.

So instead of doing this:

```
let menuWidth = <insert calculation here>
menu.width = menuWidth
```

I did this:

```
let menuWidth = <insert calculation here>
menu.width = menuWidth as CGFloat?
```