# String property returning different values when used directly or in string interpolation

Tags: swift

I've just finished debugging a situation where some of my labels were not displaying any text, despite the string in question definitely containing a value (it was printing the line before).  I eventually pinned it down to returning different values depending on the way I accessed the string.  Please note I'm *not* looking for ways to work around this, I am looking for a reason I am missing  as to why this behaviour happens.

I had a protocol with the following *optional* String property, set to default to `nil`:

```
protocol SomeProtocol {
    var titleString: String? { get }
}

extension SomeProtocol {
    var titleString: String? {
        return nil
    }
}
```

Which was implemented in a class with a *not optional* String, with `title` set elsewhere:

```
class SomeClass: SomeProtocol {
    var title: String
    var titleString: String {
        return title
    }
}
```

When attempting to access the value of titleString from a `SomeClass` object, it always returned `nil`, regardless of the `title` property.  This was seen through assigning to a label like:

```
label.text = someClassInstance.titleString
```

However, when I printed the value or set the label through

```
label.text = "\(someClassInstance.titleString)"
```

everything worked, and it displayed the text.

I've narrowed the source of this down to where I've overridden the *optional* property with one not optional.  Clearly when I access the property directly it is returned by the protocol implementation, while using it by string interpolation returns the class one.  What is actually behind this behaviour?

Edit: to demonstrate this behaviour run this gist in an Xcode playground:
https://gist.github.com/CaileanWilkinson/357c17f36d04b522b9bcf1241a825d9f

Comment: Can you please post code that actually reproduces the issue? I tried your code in an Xcode 9.4 playground and I did not see `nil` either way.

Comment: @rmaddy Try assigning it to a label's `text` property and then print the label's `text` in your playground

Comment: @rmaddy It's displayed in the code in this gist: https://gist.github.com/CaileanWilkinson/357c17f36d04b522b9bcf1241a825d9f

Comment: Using a label's `text` property allowed my to reproduce the issue.

Comment: So it seems that if the result is known to be a `String?` then the `titleString` with the return type of `String?` is called. If the result is known to be a `String` then the `titleString` with the return type of `String` is called. I don't know if this is a bug in some way but it is enough info to avoid the problem.

Comment: Interesting.  I suppose Swift is looking for an exact signature match first, ignoring the inheritance order.  I would imagine it's unintentional behaviour but you're right - knowing this is enough to avoid it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I feel like this is somewhat similar to the solution of this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42174748/an-extension-hides-a-property-that-i-want-to-access-workarounds) of mine. In that question, there is also two almost identical properties - one optional, the other non-optional. And I experienced a similar situation where Swift can't figure out which property I want.

Your `titleString` in `SomeClass` is **not** overriding the `titleString` property in the protocol. This is reflected in Xcode's suggestions:

[image]

You can access both properties like this:

```
someObject.titleString as String // accesses the one in SomeClass
someObject.titleString as String? // accesses the one in the protocol
```

My point here is that the type of the expression matters. If the type of expression swift expects is `String`, then it resolves to the one in `SomeClass`. If the expected type of the expression is `String?`, then it evaluates to the one in the protocol.

This explains why setting the label's text without string interpolation will call the property in the protocol (`label.text` is `String?`, so it expects a `String?`) and why using string interpolation will call the property in `SomeClass` (String interpolation expects a non-optional).

Comment: Ah, I see.  So rather than being a Swift issue, it seems there is a bug in AppCode which was (somewhat understandably) showing `SomeClass.titleString` as implementing the `SomeProtocol.titleString` property.